# CSS "overflow:visible" not displaying elements

Tags: css, angular

I'm creating a funnel element in anglular with scss, with a possibility to have one element in the funnel to be a dynamic list that displays 3 items verticaly with borders as part of that element. If the dynamic list has more than 3 elements, a button is shown at the top that should display all the other elements of the list that are hidden with overflow: hidden. Clicking the button changes overflow to visible and a change happens, but only the border lines are displayed but not the rest of the content (like on the img).

I've tried varios combinations, changing the height of some of the containers of the list element but nothing works. I've managed to introduce a scrollbar in the list, but i'm trying to expand the list below and toggle all the items. The funnel should preserve its decreasing height distribution, so i couldn't just add height: 100% on the click event. Looking forward to suggestions/tips because i couldn't find anything online.

```
ts:
productsList = [
    {name: 'Product1', value: '42.491 $'},
    {name: 'Product2', value: '41.491 $'},
    {name: 'Product3', value: '40.491 $'},
    {name: 'Product4', value: '39.491 $'},
    {name: 'Product5', value: '38.491 $'},
    {name: 'Product6', value: '37.491 $'}
  ]
```

```
html:
<div class="funnel-container" [style.height.px]="containerHeight">
            <div [ngClass]=" i !== 2 ? 'funnel-element-container' : 'funnel-element-list-container'" [class.show-hidden-elements]="i === 2 && showHiddenElements" *ngFor="let item of funnelItems; let i = index"
              [style.backgroundColor]="getColor(i)"
              [style.height.px]="getHeight(i)" style="color: white; text-align: center;">
              <div class="funnel-element" *ngIf="i !== 2">
                <p class="content-value">
                  250.000 $
                </p>
                <span class="content-percentage">
                  88% of total 
                </span>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="i === 2" class="funnel-element-list">
                <div class="content-list-element" *ngFor="let item of productsList">
                  <span style="margin-right: 20px;">{{ item.name }}</span> <span>{{ item.value }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="arrow" *ngIf="productsList.length > 3" (click)="toggleHiddenElements()"></div>
              </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="titles-container">
              <span class="title" *ngFor="let item of funnelItems">Square</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

```
css:
.funnel-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.funnel-element-container, .funnel-element-list-container {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 240px; /* Maximum width for the funnel elements */
  position: relative; /* Add relative positioning for absolute title positioning */
  z-index: 1;
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
}
.funnel-element-container {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
.funnel-element-list-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  .content-list-element {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

}

.titles-container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute; /* Add absolute positioning to position titles */
  top: 0; /* Align titles at the top */
  left: 0; /* Align titles on the left side of the container */
  right: 0; /* Align titles on the right side of the container */
  bottom: 0; /* Align titles at the bottom */
}

.title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  // max-width: 240px;
  flex-basis: 240px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center; /* Center text horizontally within the container */
  margin: 0;
}



.funnel-element-list {
  // position: relative;
  // width: 300px;
  // height: 300px;
  // border: 1px solid #ccc;
  // overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show-hidden-elements {
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
  overflow-y: visible;
  // height: 100%;
}
```

[Behavior when clcicking on btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFIQ6.png)